# Can't connect to WAN wirelessly

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a rpi model B, internet works fine when using cat5 cables plugged into the router. I recently purchased a BUFFALO AirStation N150 Wireless USB Adapter - WLI-UC-GNM and configured it to work, or so I thought. The pi works fine on LAN, as I have been accessing it through VNC and have had no problems. When trying to connect to the internet I could not connect to any website. Some more information:

When configure to use wlan0 (Wireless adapter) the link light on the board does not illuminate
I can ping machines on my network and the local loopback
Tried to ping 8.8.8.8 and got "connect: network is unreachable", same goes for trying to ping any named website.

Everything works fine when plugged in directly to the router.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a default route. How did you configure the wireless? Statically? DHCP? If the latter, is it the same DHCP config for both wired and wireless?

Comment: Yes, I agree. The output of `/sbin/route -n` on the Pi may help a lot here.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am guessing you guys are right, there is no gateway defined for wlan. I used the wifi config tool, its DHCP. 

@Arne here is the output for route -n, how do I configure the gateway?

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
Sorry for formatting, still learning the ropes here